# CS0246: The type or namespace name '<type-name>' could not be found

Tags: c#, wpf

I know this question has been asked before but alot of the solutions don't seem to work for me.

I don't have any trouble building the solution, I feel like I'm missing something in my code maybe? I have 3 files: TEST.cs, MainControl.xaml.cs and MainControl.XAML

Here is what I have in my TEST file. I'm getting the error in the line var.mainControl = new **TEST**.MainControl();

```
    public void Execute(ScriptContext context, Window window)
    {
        var mainControl = new TEST.MainControl();
        window.Content = mainControl;
        window.Width = 800;
        window.Height = 450;
    }
```

In the MainControl.xaml.cs file I have the namespace set to TEST.cs:

```
namespace TEST
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainControl : Window
    {
        public MainControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here? My next step is to add properties to the code-behind file and bind it. I'm getting this error when I launch the TEST.cs file in another application called Varian Eclipse whose API I'm using to build this script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please tell us what line you get the error on, and clarify how it is that you're getting a compiler error when you don't have any trouble building the solution. A [reproducible example from you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would vastly simplify this process for everybody.

Comment: MainControl is a new window? I mean do you have another main window? or MainControl  is your main window?

Comment: I'm curious... what happens if you comment out `InitializeComponent()`. Same error?  Also, what exactly is 'type-name' that can't be found?

Comment: @Nehorai MainControl.xaml is the only window I will have

Comment: @CaseyCrookston type-name is TEST

Comment: Ah! That would have been good to know up front?  What namespace is `public void Execute()` in? Also, are TEST.cs, MainControl.xaml.cs in the same project?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston commenting out `InitializeComponenet()` results in the same error. `public void Execute()` is in the namespace VMS.TPS which has a comment on it and everything is in the same project: 
// Do not change namespace and class name
// otherwise Eclipse will not be able to run the script.

Comment: are TEST.cs, MainControl.xaml.cs in the same project?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Yup, they're all in the same project.

Comment: @fahadmp Please try the following: on solution explorer right click on MainControl.xaml, reanme it to MainWindow.xaml let me know if this help

Comment: @Nehorai unfortunately, no. same error